Dependancy of acid strength and volume to the column size: Column Chromatography
Is there a way to theoretically estimate the changes to be made to the acid strength and volume when the length and the inner diameter of the column capillary and hence the resin volume are changed?
Say the first column has a length of 12.5cm having an inner diameter of 4.0 mm and another column is 10cm long with an inner diameter of 3.2mm. Hence, the volume of resin would be 1.5mL and 0.8mL, respectively.
Assuming that the elements of interest remain the same in both cases, how should the acid strength and/or volume be changed to obtain similar elution profiles?
